# How to store a lot of data for one application?

Tags: content-database, remote-blob-storage

I have read that SP has a 200GB recommended max size for any content DB. I was also able to add multiple content databases to one web application.

If my app needed to store BLOB data uploaded by a user to one Document Library and over time it grew over 200GB, will this cause an error or will it store the data for one list across multiple content databases?

I'm also looking into using remote blob storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is right msft recommend 200gb size of content DB but it is not hard limit, you can go upto 4 TB or even more if you have all required hardware which mentioned in technet.

If your DB growth setting is not restricted and have plenty of space on dB server's data drive then sharepoint will continue....it will only stop if your database caped to 200gb.

I would keep only one site collection in one content dB if I know it grew upto 200gb or more.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ContentDB

Comment: Thank you. So what is the purpose of multiple content databases then?

Comment: A web application can have multiple site collections and each site collection can have a different content database.